# search exact string exist within column mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm using below sql query for search values from db, but when I search 'study' it will returns the values 'caese-study', 'get-study-materials' as well.
How can I use a query to search exact contains withing string column?

$names = 'study';
and the names column has values like comma separated,
 Ex: 'study, abc, new' so I need to search within that too

```
SELECT * FROM datatitle WHERE  names LIKE '%$names %' ;

SELECT * FROM datatitle WHERE  names regexp '(^|[[:space:]])$names([[:space:]]|$)';
```

I try with above two queries but didnt work as expect, pls advice?

Comment: `names="study"`?

Comment: stop using `LIKE` use `=`, e.g `SELECT * FROM datatitle WHERE  names= '$names' ;
`

Comment: @Curious_Mind names column has comma separated data so will it work for that?

Comment: @SanduniDi You should have mentioned that in the question from the start. Now I feel I have to reopen this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry I have updated my question

Comment: I've reopened this. Hint: You'll need to use `IN()` for this or possibly `FIND_IN_SET()` but unsure on the latter.

Comment: Should probably normalize the table. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: SPLIT_STRING with where in?

Answer (score 2):

You should not be storing comma-separated values in a column.  You should be using a junction/association table.  You should fix the data model, if you can.

However, sometimes we cannot control other people's really bad decisions.  MySQL has `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT dt.*
FROM datatitle dt
WHERE find_in_set(?, names) > 0;
```

Note that I have replaced the constant `$names` with a parameter.  You should learn to use parameters to pass values into queries.